# Varnish cache crashed

Tags: varnish, amazon-elb

We are using two Varnish cache behind aws elb. And traffic coming through aws cloudfront. All of a sudden both varnish service crashed, It happens only once. Anybody has any similar experience or any advise on this? There is no hints in server log or elb log!

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 7

Varnish: varnish-3.0.2 revision 55e70a4

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The last released version of Varnish 3.0 (before it was defined as end of life) was 3.0.7. There are significant bugfixes between 3.0.2 and 3.0.7.

You can try to ask the Debian maintenance team for help, but I wouldn't hold my breath.